# Stateless request to KIE Server REST API

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

We are using the latest Docker images of Business Central and KIE-server, and are interacting with the rules service client using KIE's REST API.

We created a set of rules in Business Central that, when fired, insert a "Response" fact.

We would like to be able to sent requests to KIE Server in a stateless manner; i.e. every time we send a request (typically composed of a chain the following chain of commands: insert-object -> fire-all-rules -> get-objects) to the server, no objects/facts from a previous requests should be returned by the get-objects command.

From what we understand, one way to go about this would be to create a new session for each request. How would one do that?
Any other suggestions and/or references?

Comment: Are you currently getting back objects/facts from previous requests?

Comment: Yes, until I reset the docker image of KIE Server, all the facts either inserted through a request or upon rule firing persist, and I can retrieve them with a get-objects request.

Comment: Did you configure kie server to use stateless sessions?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Indeed, I had not configured KIE Server to use stateless session. The following Stack explains how to do it in Business Central (see Q1 response): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627740/how-to-invoke-decision-service-as-a-stateless-session-in-kie-redhat-decision-ma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stateless API calls will work once a stateless session is defined. In your API call, refer to the stateless session using the "lookup" key.
Here is a reference to another StackOverflow which explains how to create the stateless session in Businsess Central: [How to invoke decision service as a stateless session in Kie (RedHat Decision Manager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627740/how-to-invoke-decision-service-as-a-stateless-session-in-kie-redhat-decision-ma)